# Let's agree on this so that we might/may go home early

Tags: modal-verbs, subjunctives

> **MIGHT** (used with another phrase or clause to express the condition, purpose,
> or result of something):
>
> *Let's agree on this so that* (as a result) *we **might**/may go home early*
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/definition/might

Collins's **may** reads "6. another word for [might](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/might)"

> **MIGHT** 2. (often followed by well) expressing theoretical possibility: he *might* well come. In this sense *might* looks to the future and functions as a weak form of *may*. See **may1**

Is *might* in the example *we **might**/may go home early* a subjunctive? what triggers it?

Comment: Not one native English speaker in a hundred knows of or practises any rule (if one exists) regarding the use of **may** and **might**. They are used interchangeably in all situations.

Comment: @ronaldsole https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=might

Comment: @GIC I think that your source gives a fine exposition but I would wager a substantial sum that not one native English speaker in a hundred had come across it.  And I might (not **may**) alter my earlier comment to read **in nearly all situations** or, at least, the great majority. I constantly hear BBC newsreaders using **may** where I'd prefer **might**.  The wo/man in the street wouldn't have a clue.

Answer (score 2):

The rule regarding may and might is simple that can be summarized as follows.

May is used formally in the following three situations.

- Something that is allowed/not allowed: You may travel for free. You may not pass.*1
- Asking for/giving permission: May I have that last piece of cake? You may eat the cake.*1
- Make a guess about something in the present or future: Johns may visit tomorrow.

*1. We can also use 'can' instead of may.

Both may and might are used formally in the following situations.

- Make a guess about something in the present or future: John may/might visit tomorrow.
- A very polite way of asking for permission: Might I have that last piece of cake? (chiefly British)

Might is used in the following situation.

- The past tense of permission using may: He said that he might do it.

Source: [The British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/may-and-might)

Not let's analyze your statement based on the above rules.

- Let's agree on this so that we might/may go home early.

In the above statement, we are not sure about the outcome. As per the grammar rule, you can use both may and might.
The verb might/may in the sentence indicate a conditional state rather than a subjunctive state, which reflect a wish/desire that cannot become true as, "if I were a butterfly, I would fly".

Note: The other states include the indicative (indicate a reality), the imperative (command), and the interrogative (question).

Comment: Using _may have_ for a past counterfactual situation instead of _might have_ can lead to confusion, since _may have_ is best suited for a different kind of situation: present uncertainty about a past situation https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=might